# Beginner - While Loop Troubles

Tags: python, while-loop

For my studies, I have begun to learn the Python Programming Language.

Fairly new to programming and having some trouble understanding why this won't work.

```
while compReady == False: 
    compAI = input("Which strategy for the computer [1,2,3]? ")
    if compAI == "1" or "2" or "3":
        compReady = True
    elif compAI != "1" or "2" or "3":
        print("Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.")
```

The problem I have is that no matter what is inputted into compAI, it runs through the 'if' statement. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: what if you reordered the conditions (`or` is commutative) so that you had `if "2" or "3" or compAI == "1":`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` condition should be written as ..

```
 if compAI == ("1" or "2" or "3"):
```

In your code, Python interpreter will treat `"2"` and `"3"` as `true`. Please note it is not compared with compAI as per `if` statement syntax.